# Parse json file with node and gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Right now I'm browserifying my code in the gulpfile, and sending it to the appropriate location. however if I want to parse a json file and display it within index.html...

it returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require(...).readFileSync is not a function
```

Here is my code http://pastebin.com/n0BJfZG9 of my gulpfile and app.js

Am I missing something? Why can't I use normal node modules for this kind of thing?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using `fs`. You need to import just `fs` then use the `fs.readFileSync()`

Comment: @The added code. sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to require your JSON file directly in node:

```
var myJson = require('./path/to/file.json');

// log to confirm output
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

This assumes `file.json` is raw JSON, along the lines of:

```
{
  "property": "value",
  "property2": "value2"
}
```